# How long does it take to change states of matter?

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase

I'm interested to know how long it takes to change states of matter and why it takes the time that it does.  For example, what is the very quickest that we could freeze a packet of chicken breasts?  In the food industry, flash freezing is often used to prevent damage from occurring by freezing meat very quickly.  But why does it take the time that it does?  Would it be possible to freeze my packet of chicken in say, a nano second instead of a few minutes?

Comment: It's rather for Physis SE

Comment: I think it's fine for Chem SE. States of matter and interrelations thereof are perfectly cromulent area of chemistry.

Comment: Heat transfer takes time.  The greater the temperature difference the faster heat transfer but it still takes time.  Even at absolute zero I doubt you could freeze a packet of chicken in a nano second.  Also it is expensive to create very low temperatures.

Comment: I understand that but why does it take the time it does?  What dictates the time it takes for the change of state to occur?  Is there some absolute constant at work here which cannot be got around or will human ingenuity continue to find new ways of freezing faster?

Comment: A change of state has set amount of energy.   You must transfer that amount of heat.    A bigger temperature difference and bigger contact area will speed the heat transfer.  Heat is real and a bit broad.  Humans are not going to be able to trick heat into finding  faster path.  With a microwave you can blast it with radiant energy for a fast heat add.  But there is not a negative radiant to suck the heat out as radiant.  You are stuck with conduction and convection for cooling.

Comment: Thanks Frisbee, most enlightening.  Can I ask the question the other way round. Using a microwave over as an example, why does it take the time it does take to bring a frozen packet of chicken to room temperature?  Obviously, throwing more energy at it would make the change of states occur faster but is there a ceiling?  If we were to throw a very large amount of energy at the frozen chicken, in the form of microwaves, would we be able to make the change from frozen to room temp occur in say, a nano second?

Comment: @SeaCat The nature of heat, temperature, and entropy is bit broad.    I am not seeing the piratical value of the question.

Comment: Let's say I was working in the food industry and am interested in finding ways to freeze and unfreeze quicker.  Traditional forms of freezing are pretty slow and during the freezing process, ice crystals form both inside each cell in the meat and between cells.  The ice crystals burst the cells open spilling their contents.  So traditionally frozen meat can never taste as good as fresh meat which has not been frozen.

Comment: But what if the meat were frozen so quickly that ice crystals did not have time to grow.  Then they could not cause any damage and, when defrosted, the meat ought to be as tasty as fresh meat.  But how to reduce the freezing time to the extent that ice crystals cannot form?  That's the question.  Now you know the context, does that help?

Comment: Flash freezing is established and the objective is not nanosecond or even as fast as possible.   Flash freeze is simply fast enough not to form ice crystals.  It is well established that liquid nitrogen is fast enough.    Flash freezing does not require nanosecond so no I do not get the context of your question.

Comment: That's true but there is no harm in trying to advance the process further.  If we were all content with the status quo nothing would ever move forward.  So the goal in this hyperthetical situation, is to freeze my packet of chicken in a few nano seconds and bring it back to room temperature from frozen, again in just a few nano seconds.  But why stop there.  What I'm interested in knowing is why things like this take the amount of time that they do.  I mean, why couldn't the process be speeded up even more so that my chicken is frozen in say, a few pico seconds?

Comment: It's not really the chicken I'm concerned with here - just the reasons why the time it takes is the time it takes.  What's the underlying rule that makes things happen in the time we experience them happening in our world?

Answer (score 4):

Part of the answer is that the rate of freezing depends on the heat of fusion of the material being frozen (relatively large for water, the chief ingredient of uncooked chicken), but smaller for other substances).

Another piece of the answer is that an object can lose heat by convection, conduction, and/or radiation. You would increase the rate of heat loss by:

(1) increasing the surface area of the chicken as much as possible (flattening it),

(2) placing it against a surface held as cold as possible and made of a material such as metal with high heat capacity;

(3) hitting it with a continuous blast of extremely cold air or gas at the highest possible wind speed (remember wind chill factor?) and maximizing radiant heat loss by previously having painted the chicken with flat, black paint and conducting the experiment in a mirrored, insulated chamber. Some unusual materials can be induced to cool by irradiation with a laser (this is how we have obtained the lowest recorded temperatures ever) but this will probably not work with chicken.

I do not think there is an absolute limit on cooling rate, just diminishing returns for increasing energy expenditure. But I may be wrong. I hope you pursue this until you get an answer that satisfies you. That is how new discoveries are made.

Comment: Just spaced out the paragraphs a bit - makes this good answer clearer to read.